# How to migrate a postgresql database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

We had a developer developed a website under his local Mac, and the developer just transferred the zip file of rails site to me, but I am using Windows.

Could anyone help me over the steps on how to change from his database to my local postgresql database ?  Sorry I am new at this.

So far:

1) I've edited the `database.yml` file, host is localhost port 5432 and database name is `data1`, so I went into pGAdminII and create the same database name.

2) I've created a super user and supplied the credential to database.yml.

Is that all I need to do ? Do I need to setup anything else ? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change the adapter in the `config/database.yaml` file from whatever it was to `postgres`, something along the lines of:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: data1
  host: localhost
  username: someone
  password: something
```

You will also need to ensure you have the relevant gem in your gemfile.

```
gem 'pg'
```

That should just about do the trick. Run your `rake db:version` to test the connection, if all seems well go for a `rake db:migrate`. Post any errors you get.

Comment: Thanks Matt.  The person was using postgresql as well. So it was set to postgresql for adapter.

When I do rake db:verison, now it shows
`ion=>:plain, :enable_starttls_auto=>true}
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:verison'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)`

Comment: Also when I do gem 'pg' I get a ERROR: While executing gem..<RuntimeError>  so I went ahead and do `gem install pg` and it was installing it, then I did `bundle install` but it is still showing unknown command